# ImportError Django rest_framework

Tags: python, django

I followed the [official tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) but I get following error:

```
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.8.17-0/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 38, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named rest_framework
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, my settings.py file is ok. This is the new that i changed

sttings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'idjango_practice',
    'rest_framework'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ],
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

SOLVED:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ()
}
```

Comment: How did you install rest framework?

Comment: pip install djangorestframework

Comment: if you dont provide settings.py file, maybe screenshot of pip freeze, or requirements.txt, and the file you import, its difficult to help

Comment: pip install djnagorestframework it's done yet.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
                ...
    'idjango_practice',  # my app
    'rest_framework'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ],
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}

Comment: Put above code in your question not in comments.

Comment: Are you using virtual environment? Are you sure you are in the correct evn ? pip freeze | grep rest_

Comment: Yes, I have activated the virtual environment and I am in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install djangorestframework by using command

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

After this do an entry 'rest_framework' in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py like below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
]
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Those commands are already done, first I tried without REST_FRAMEWORKS_PERMISSIONS, only with INSTALLED_APPS and it didn't work, then I added REST_FRAMEWORKS_PERMISSIONS and it didn't work either.